# Undelete for an user

Tags: discussion

I wanted to share a question asked on MSE about a question deleted on SF due to the fact it was abandonned, the OP wanted to post a answer in it.

The question asking for direction wasnt migrated there yet, kinda odd, I even flagged it, but I think they want to keep it on MSE for futur reference in such case, but anyway there it’s;

[What should I do if I find the answer to an old question of mine that was automatically deleted as abandoned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309526/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-the-answer-to-an-old-question-of-mine-that-was-automa)

and the related question is;

https://serverfault.com/questions/840395/implementing-pppoe-half-bridge-ip-passthrough-to-suit-ipsec-vpn-firewall-applian

I wanted to share it before anyone think Iam on a rampage to cast undelete vote :) to see why I casted it is important imo, and without a metapost its odd.

Comment: No need to explain a vote, but in this case it's good you did (question undeleted)...